# Sqlite index seemingly broken after insertion, need to run ANALYZE which is locking

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sqlite query gets really slow after inserting 14,300,160 rows (the db size is about 3G).

Supposed I have a table called `test` and I have created an index on column `TIMESTAMP` prior to insertion. A simple

```
SELECT DISTINCT TIMESTAMP FROM test;
```

Would run about **40 seconds**, but after I do:

```
ANALYZE; -- Takes 1 minute or so on this DB
```

The same query runs **40 milliseconds**, which is expected since the column is indexed.

As I'm using the database for soft real time applications, it is not possible to lock the DB for 1 minute or so just to run `ANALYZE` from time to time. I suspect that the insertion is breaking the index, hence the `ANALYZE` helped. Is that really the case? And if so, is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#manctrl).

Comment: @CL if I understand correctly, one still has to manually run `ANALYZE` for the statistics to be useful, is that right?

Comment: How many distinct timestamps will there be?

Comment: @CL. A little under 3000, which isn't too bad, each timestamp has 5000+ rows

Comment: Are you sure that the difference is due to the ANALYZE, and not because the data was in the cache for the second query?

Comment: @CL. yes I'm quite sure. I ran them a number of times separately, with "closing/re-opening" db files

Comment: What is the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output in both cases?

Comment: @CL. the same: "scanning table with covering index timestamp_idx" which is an index I created on column `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Then the runtime cannot be different.

Comment: Any other columns included in timestamp_idx?

Comment: @Ben no, time stamp is the only one